# LLVM: how can I get the struct name that the StoreInst operates on?

Tags: clang, llvm, fuzzing

recently I am trying to monitor the struct accessment using LLVM.

I can print the StoreInst using the SI.dump() as

```
i32* getelementptr inbounds (%struct._Datatype, %struct._Datatype* @monitor_memory, i32 0, i32 0)
```

But in the pass code, I can't find a method for StoreInst to get just the Struct name, which I want to use to do the compare laterly.

```
if (type->getStructName() == "struct._Datatype") {
    ....
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!
the code fragment is here:

```
     for(BasicBlock &B : F) {
      for(Instruction &I : B) {
        StoreInst * store = nullptr;
        builder->SetInsertPoint(&I);
         if((store = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(&I)) != nullptr) {
            Value * value = store->getValueOperand(); // Getting the value to be stored at given address
            Value * address = store->getPointerOperand(); // Getting source address
            Type * type = store->getPointerOperandType(); // the type that I get is i32*, but I expect it to be struct._Datatype.
       
         }
      }
    }
```

the Datatype defined as

```
    typedef struct _Datatype {
        int a;
        int b;
    } Datatype;
```

Answer (score 1):

Names are generally obtained using getName() in LLVM, for the kinds of objects that may have names. The StructType class has a [getName()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1StructType.html#aff252107dbc6129b4dacaac73dd673dd), so all you need is

```
cast<StructType>(type)->getName()
```

Comment: thanks！but when I try to do the cast, type->isStructTy() return false. I guess that is because the operant is a GEP?

Comment: GEP returns a pointer to something. GEP It doesn't return a struct. is `type->isPointerTy()` true? yes? GEP takes a pointer to a struct as input, so if that is the struct you want, you have to look at the GEP's operands a bit and take the type of the right operand.